# При редиректе домена на WWW, подставляется index.php, как исправить?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так в коде? 
Почему когда пытаюсь зайти на сайт по ссылке без WWW , меня редиректит на www.site.ru/index.php?q=sss/sss/sss, вместо www.site.ru/sss/sss/sss

Когда просто перехожу по ссылкам с WWW, все отрабатывает должным образом.

Вот пример моего .htaccess.

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
php_flag register_globals 0

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On



RewriteBase /

############################################################################
#### Убираем повторяющиеся слеши (/) в URL                              ####
############################################################################
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{1,}$
   # Проверяем, повторяется ли слеш (//) более двух раз.
RewriteRule . %1%2 [R=301,L]
   # Исключаем все лишние слеши.



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?q=$0 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну чтож....сам спросил, сам ответил....

В общем помагла такая реализация:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
php_flag register_globals 0

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options -Indexes
```

Во первых поменял условия редиректа на index.php, а также поменял правила местами, вроде работает, еще тестить буду... но вроде робит!

Comment: Просто теперь к параметрам адресной строки обращаюсь не через $_GET[q'], а через $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].